# A difficulty to understand a latex error message

Tags: errors, pstricks

I have this error message that I don't understand.

> ...rrowLoaded\endinput\else\input   pst-arrow
>                                                   \fi
>   Please type another input file name

Please if you can help me

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: error message starts a bit earlier this is not enough to decode the problem

Comment: latex is trying to input a file it can not find but you have only shown a small fragment of the error message so hard to help. please show the full error from the log from `!` in a code block `{}` not quote so line endings are preserved.

Comment: Just a guess: `pst-arrow` is a recent package, which was a part of `pstricks-add` previously. Try 1) updating your installation; 2) installing `pst-arrow`.

Comment: update your system or put  http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-arrow/tex/pst-arrow.tex into your documents directory if you have not the right to update the system.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).